# Query a child element of a queried element

Tags: react-testing-library

I want to check how many elements there are within the parent element that I have queried

```
    renderWithRouterMatch(Planner, {
        route: '/planner/5ed7aee4739/5f187e21bef',
        path: '/planner/:guideBookId/:tripId',
    });
    const spotBoard = await screen.findByTestId('spot-board');

    const cardsInSpotBoard = spotBoard.findAllByTestId('spot-card');
    expect(cardsInSpotBoard.length).toBe(6);
});
```

So, I am able to get the `spotBoard` element. There are a number of elements in the `spotBoard` element, and I want to check if the right number of them have been rendered.

But i'm getting this error: `TypeError: spotBoard.findByTestId is not a function`

I've tried googling how to query elements within an element and I wasn't getting any results. Is this the right approach? Or how should I do it?

Would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

`findByTestId` returns a `Promise` which resolves to an `HTMLElement` so you can use the `spot-board` element with `within` to find the `spot-card` test ids inside of it.

```js
it("should count the length of spot cards", async () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);

  const spotBoard = await getByTestId("spot-board");
  const cardsInSpotBoard = await within(spotBoard).findAllByTestId('spot-card');

  expect(cardsInSpotBoard.length).toBe(6);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a top-level query functions with a `container` as its first argument. From [the Queries page](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#bytestid):

```js
getByTestId(
  container: HTMLElement, // if you're using `screen`, then skip this argument
  text: TextMatch,
  options?: {
    exact?: boolean = true,
    normalizer?: NormalizerFn,
  }): HTMLElement
```

In your example, you can do it like this:

```js
import {findAllByTestId, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

renderWithRouterMatch(Planner, {
    route: '/planner/5ed7aee4739/5f187e21bef',
    path: '/planner/:guideBookId/:tripId',
});
const spotBoard = await screen.findByTestId('spot-board');

const cardsInSpotBoard = await findAllByTestId(spotBoard, 'spot-card');
expect(cardsInSpotBoard.length).toBe(6);
```